# Got error in api test case using rSpec in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

I am developing application where using `Rails 4`. I am just starting writing test cases but got issue in login API test case using `rSpec and capybara`.

Below is controller file of `API`

```
---------------------- app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb --------------

class Api::UsersController < Api::ApiController
  before_action :set_user_api, except: [:login] 

  api :GET, '/api/users/login', "Get user token using credentials"
  param :email, String, "User email", :required => true
  param :password, String, "User password", :required => true
  def login
    @user= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user != nil && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if @user.token == nil
        @user.generate_token
        @user.save!
      end
      render action: 'withKey'
    else
      error(401, 401, "Could not authenticate user")
    end
  end
end
```

It is run success using get method in POSTMAN

I coded for it in test cases below:

```
------------------------ spec/helpers/api/users_helper_spce.rb ----------------

require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::UsersHelper, :type => :request do

    describe "Test Login Api" do
       it "Login Api" do
        params = {
                :email => "two@gmail.com",
                :password => "12345678"
        }

        get "/api/users/login", params
        # puts response.inspect
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
       end
    end
end
```

I got error below:

```
  1) Api::UsersHelper Test Login Api Login Api
     Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(200)

       expected: 200
            got: 401

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/helpers/api/users_helper_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Credential which i used in api that i use for login in site and its success.

What is wrong.. that i can't found.

Any one experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a user before signing him.
If you use *FactoryGirls* gem it will be something like this

```
let(:user) {Factory(:user, email: "two@gmail.com", password: "12345678")}
describe "Test Login Api" do
  before { user }
  it "Login Api" do
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RSpec.describe Api::UsersHelper, :type => :request do   
    describe "Test Login Api" do
           it "Login Api" do
            params = {
                       :email => "abc@gmail.com",
                       :password => "12345678"
               }

               create_user("abc", "xyz", params[:email], params[:password])
               get "/api/users/login", params
               expect(response.status).to eq(200)
           end
    end
end
```

i added one method which register user first because of test cases use test database and its blank every time. So  i can't found user data thats why need to create user first.